# Are the spell descriptions detailing movements a part of the spell's somatic component? For example with Message "you point your finger"

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, spell-components

I am specifically asking this, whether Subtle Spell would eliminate all signs of casting a spell or not, as many have additional movements or actions described in them. Message needs pointing a finger and whispering for example.

Comment: I closed your questions since it has been addressed in the linked post, even with respect to another spell. If you believe that yours significantly differs from the proposed dupe, you may explain why and where the differences are.

Comment: Related: [Can I successfully cast the Message cantrip targeting a familiar creature in range when I have no idea where they are to "point toward"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/197257/75095)

Comment: Also related: [How can flameskulls cast fireball without fingers?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/184439/how-can-flameskulls-cast-fireball-without-fingers)

Comment: Since this question was closed as a duplicate, I added an answer to the linked duplicate target, [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/208150/75095). (I think its not a great duplicate target, as that question is mixed up with things that are specific to *burning hands*, but I have no will to get into a discussion on that.)

Comment: @NobodytheHobgoblin This seems like a pretty straightforward dupe.